# how am I copying this html into itself?

Tags: python, html

Ive got a very simple html. with a few divs in it to fill with data.
below is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GOG  init</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1> GOG  new :) </h1>
   <div id = "card1"><div id ="name1"></div><div id ="price1"></div></div>
   <div id = "card2"><div id ="name2"></div><div id ="price2"></div></div>
   <div id = "card3"><div id ="name3"></div><div id ="price3"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

i have written a python script which grabs some data from gog.com to fill the html and i fill the html below by simply replacing 2 lines.

```
#bunch of stuff to get names n prices ...... 

of= open("index.html","r")
html_page=of.read()
of.close()

with open("index.html","w") as f:
    to_replace='<div id = "card1"><div id ="name1">{}</div><div id ="price1">{}</div></div>'.format(name1 , price1)
    f.write(re.sub(r'<div id = "card1"><div id ="name1"></div><div id ="price1"></div></div>', to_replace, html_page))
    to_replace='<div id = "card2"><div id ="name2">{}</div><div id ="price2">{}</div></div>'.format(name2 , price2)
    f.write(re.sub(r'<div id = "card2"><div id ="name2"></div><div id ="price2"></div></div>', to_replace, html_page))
```

Below you can see the final result of my html. it seems to copy itself, including parts of the head.

```
<body>
<h1> GOG  new :) </h1>
   <div id="card1"><div id="name1">Pillars of Eternity II: Deadfire - Obsidian Edition ,,,  Outward</div><div id="price1">18.00</div></div>
   <div id="card2"><div id="name2"></div><div id="price2"></div></div>
   <div id="card3"><div id="name3"></div><div id="price3"></div></div>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GOG  init</title>

   <h1> GOG  new :) </h1>
   <div id="card1"><div id="name1"></div><div id="price1"></div></div>
   <div id="card2"><div id="name2">Outward</div><div id="price2">13.99</div></div>
   <div id="card3"><div id="name3"></div><div id="price3"></div></div>

</body>
```

How does it copy the whole thing? what am i doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are writing two times html_page in file. You are changing a string in html page and print the whole html_page, then sub another string from the original file and then write it again. I changed the first substitution to be saved in html_page variable. That string will go again under re.sub() and then be written in file.

```
#bunch of stuff to get names n prices ...... 

of= open("index.html","r")
html_page=of.read()
of.close()

with open("index.html","w") as f:
    to_replace='<div id = "card1"><div id ="name1">{}</div><div id ="price1">{}</div></div>'.format(name1 , price1)
    html_page = re.sub(r'<div id = "card1"><div id ="name1"></div><div id ="price1"></div></div>', to_replace, html_page))
    to_replace='<div id = "card2"><div id ="name2">{}</div><div id ="price2">{}</div></div>'.format(name2 , price2)
    f.write(re.sub(r'<div id = "card2"><div id ="name2"></div><div id ="price2"></div></div>', to_replace, html_page))
```